# Update only key from a key/value property file?

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to tackle a program take the given input file is `in.properties` and I want to write it out again to a new file `out.properties` discarding the prefix `prefix` from the file contents

i.e. the contents of the input file would be

```
prefix.sum.code.root=/compile/pkg
```

the contents of the output file would be

```
sum.code.root=/compile/pkg
```

Here is my Code :

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Dummy {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Properties prop =new Properties();

    try{
        //load a property file
        prop.load(new FileInputStream    ("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ant\\Filtering\\input.properties"));
        for (String key : prop.stringPropertyNames()){ 
            prop.remove(key);
        }
        prop.store(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ant\\Filtering\\output.properties"), null);          
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }}
```

The returning null value for the 'KEY' and i am not able to update new value into this feild

Comment: Can you provide the code? It will be easier to detect what goes wrong.

Comment: *"But i am not able to update/set new value into this key"* what have you tried? Based on the `Properties` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) it should be pretty straightforward to use `setProperty()` or `put()` method for this. How exactly did that fail for you?

Comment: could you paste the code you already tried to write? What is exactly your problem (what do you expect and what do you observe instead)?

Comment: Chances are you're attempting to `remove` using the prefix-stripped property name. This is just a guess, however... we can't really help until you post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this fairly easy using [`Properties.stringPropertyNames`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#stringPropertyNames%28%29) and [`Hashtable.remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29), as `Properties` is a subclass of `Hashtable`.

```
final Properties properties = ...;
for (final String name : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
  if (name.startsWith("prefix.")) {
    properties.setProperty(name.substring(6, name.length()), properties.remove(name));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks veer, i have modified my code according to your suggestion , it worked out.thanks

Comment: PS @Navneet since you appear newer here, please don't forget to mark the answer [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which helped most in solving the problem.